# CakePHP: $this->RequestHandler->getClientIP() doesn't do anything

Tags: cakephp

In my hitcount system, I try to capture the IP of the current 'hitter' and keep this session for one hour.

Part of the function:

```
 $this->Session->write('hit_ip', $this->RequestHandler->getClientIP());
```

If I echo the hit_ip session, or:

```
 echo $this->RequestHandler->getClientIP());
```

It echo's '1::1'

How should I use this function? Yes I added the requestHandler to the Components var in my app_controller

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::1` *is* the client IP address.

If you're using this on a test server on your own computer, you're mostly likely opening it at the address `http://localhost`. Internally that's looped back to your own computer. The server can only tell you where it received the request from, which in the case of a local loopback request is the local loopback address. In IPv4 that used to be `127.0.0.1`, in IPv6, which your computer is apparently preferring, that's `::1`.

If you actually accessed the app from another computer, you'd see a different address.